Iterating Inverse Images of functions
Let $f:X\to X$ be a function. Then we know that if $S\subseteq X$ then
$f[S]:=\{f(x)\vert x\in S \}$ is the image of the function and that
$f^{-1}[S]=\{y\in X\vert \exists x[x\in S\land f(x)=y]\}$ is the inverse image
Now from here we can define the following infinite family of functions recursively:
$f^0:X\to X$ where $f^0(x)=x$ for all $x\in X$;
$f^n:X\to X$ and $f^{n+1}:X\to X$ such that $f^{n+1}(x)=f(f^n(x))$ for all $x\in X$;
So naturally we get
$f^n[S]=\{f^n(x)\vert x\in S \}$ for all $S\subseteq X$ as the image of $f^n$ and similarly
$(f^n)^{-1}[S]:=\{y\in X\vert \exists x[x\in S\land f^n(x)=y]\}$
Finally we can define the following sets:
$(f^{-1})^0[S]:=S$;
$(f^{-1})^{n+1}:=(f^{-1})[(f^{-1})^n[S]]$;
Which brings me to my question. Are there any theorems about $(f^n)^{-1}[S]$ and $(f^{-1})^n[S]$. Are they the same set? Do we have to make any specific assumptions to ensure that they are the same set?

They are equal.
First note that $f^{n+1}(x) = f^n(f(x))$ for all $n\geq 1$. Indeed, this holds for $n=1$ by definition. And if $f^{k+1}(x) = f^k(f(x))$, then $f^{k+2}(x) = f(f^{k+1}(x)) = f(f^k(f(x)) = f^{k+1}(f(x))$, using induction and the definition, which proves the claim.
We prove the equality $(f^{-1})^n[S] = (f^n)^{-1}[S]$ by induction.
For $n=1$, this is simply the assertion that $f^{-1}[S] = f^{-1}[S]$.
Assume the result holds for $k$ for any $S$. We verify that $(f^{k+1})^{-1}[S] = (f^{-1})^{k+1}[S]$.
Let $x\in (f^{k+1})^{-1}[S]$. Then $f^{k+1}(x)\in S$; therefore, $f^{k}(f(x))\in S$, so $f(x)\in (f^{k})^{-1}[S] = (f^{-1})^k[S]$.
Since $f(x)\in (f^{-1})^k[S]$, then by definition this means that $x\in f^{-1}((f^{-1})^k[S]) = (f^{-1})^{k+1}[S]$. Thus, we have shown that
$$(f^{k+1})^{-1}[S]\subseteq (f^{-1})^{k+1}[S].$$
Conversely, let $y\in (f^{-1})^{k+1}[S] = f^{-1}((f^{-1})^k[S])$. Then $f(y) \in (f^{-1})^k[S] = (f^k)^{-1}[S]$, this means that $f^k(f(y))\in S$. But $f^k(f(y)) = f^{k+1}(y)$, so $f^{k+1}(y)\in S$, proving that $y\in (f^{k+1})^{-1}[S]$. Thus, we have shown that
$$ (f^{-1})^{k+1}[S] \subseteq (f^{k+1})^{-1}[S].$$
This proves the desired equality.

This is also a consequence of the following more general result:
Theorem. let $f\colon X\to Y$ and $g\colon Y\to Z$ be functions. Then $(gf)^{-1} = g^{-1}\circ f^{-1}$, where $(gf)^{-1}\colon P(Z)\to P(X)$, $f^{-1}\colon P(Y)\to P(X)$, and $g^{-1}\colon P(Z)\to P(Y)$ are the inverse image functions associated to $f$, $g$, and $gf$.
Proof. Let $S$ be a subseteq of $Z$. If $x\in (gf)^{-1}[S]$, then $gf(x)\in S$; therefore, $g(f(x))\in S$, so $f(x)\in g^{-1}[S]$, hence by definition $x\in f^{-1}[g^{-1}[S]] = (f^{-1}\circ g^{-1})[S]$.
Conversely, if $x\in (f^{-1}\circ g^{-1})[S] = f^{-1}[g^{-1}[S]]$, then $f(x)\in f^{-1}[S]$, hence $g(f(x))\in S$, so $(gf)(x)\in S$. Therefore, $x\in (gf)^{-1}[S]$.
Thus, $(gf)^{-1}[S] = f^{-1}[g^{-1}[S]]$ for all $S$, and we are done.~$\Box$
Now the result you want follows:
$$(f^{n+1})^{-1} = (f^{n}f)^{-1} = (f^{-1})(f^n)^{-1} = (f^{n+1})^{-1},$$
as desired.

Thanks a lot. I've been genuinely stuck on how to prove this for some time now. You've been a great help
